# Embedding of Gorenstein orbifold as a hypersurface

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, orbifolds

I am trying to understand if three complex dimensional orbifold singularity $\mathbb{C}^3 / \Gamma$ can be embedded as hypersurface in $\mathbb{C}^4$. The condition of being Gorenstein and having isolated singularities is simply saying that $\Gamma$ should be Abelian and for every nontrivial $g \in \Gamma$, $g$ does not have $1$ as an eigenvalue.

This [paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/hep-th/9908008.pdf) argues that such singularity cannot be embedded in $\mathbb{C}^4$, but can be embedded as complete intersections in $\mathbb{C}^n$ for large enough $n$.

However, one can imagine taking Groebner basis of the ideal in the affine variety. Since Groebner basis has the effect of eliminating variables, one should arrive at one generator of the ideal containing four variables, and the rest $n-4$ variable can be completely determined. Therefore one should get a hypersurface in $\mathbb{C}^4$.

What is wrong in the above consideration? Can such singularities be realized as hypersurface in $\mathbb{C}^4$?

Comment: "Since Groebner basis has the effect of eliminating variables" I'm not quite sure what that means. It sounds like you want to take a Noether normalization, effectively. But the map to the Noether normalization need not be an isomorphism.

Comment: @AllenKnutson What I mean by "eliminating variables" is that Grobner basis would result in so-called "elimination ideal", where the generator of the original ideal defining the relation would organize in such a way that variables appear one by one instead of mixing with each other. Therefore, some variables will be determined by others. Do you mean that the isomorphism fails even if we do so?

Comment: Maybe you're using some special property of the singularity. If not, explain what you mean in say the case $I = \langle x^2-y^2\rangle$ in the variables $x$ and $y$. Neither choice of initial term allows you to eliminate a variable.

Comment: @AllenKnutson Allen, I think I see what is the problem. One can not eliminate $z$ in the ideal $I = \langle x^2 - y^2, z^2 - x - y \rangle$ either. It will fail to to be an isomorphism.

Comment: At any rate, the embedding dimension of the isolated singularity, i.e., the dimension of $\mathfrak{m}/\mathfrak{m}^2$ as a $\mathbb{C}$-vector space, is a lower bound on the dimension of any affine space into which the quotient can (locally) be embedded.  For example, for the standard scaling action of the 3rd roots of unity on $\mathbb{C}^3$, the embedding dimension equals $10$, and the quotient is the cone over the triple Veronese embedding of the projective plane.